# VSCode Remote - Add to Existing - Breaks Container

Tags: php, apache, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I have a LAMP app that is running with a docker-compose deployment.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
app_web:
    depends_on:
      - app_db
    build: ./web
    ports: 
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./web/www:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=appdb
      - MYSQL_USER=appuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
  FROM php:7.4-apache

  WORKDIR /var/www

  RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

  RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y git
  RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

  RUN a2enmod rewrite

  COPY ./www /var/www/html
```

This works perfectly, with `localhost:3000` providing me with a working web app.

I wanted to use VSCode Remote Containers to improve my debugging. Step 1 is getting it added to my docker instance.

I've hit `Remote Containers: Add Development Container Configuration` and selected "From docker-compose.yaml" then selected `app_web`. I can then re-open in the container.

This spins up something that in Docker Desktop looks like it did before, however, Apache is not running, and when I start it with `service apache2 start` it doesn't have access to the ENV variables I've set from PHP, which it did just fine when I originally started it.

**.devcontainer\devcontainer.json:**

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/devcontainer.json or this file's README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.122.1/containers/docker-existing-docker-compose
// If you want to run as a non-root user in the container, see .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml.
{
    "name": "Existing Docker Compose (Extend)",

    // Update the 'dockerComposeFile' list if you have more compose files or use different names.
    // The .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml file contains any overrides you need/want to make.
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "..\\docker-compose.yaml",
        "docker-compose.yml"
    ],

    // The 'service' property is the name of the service for the container that VS Code should
    // use. Update this value and .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml to the real service name.
    "service": "app_web",

    // The optional 'workspaceFolder' property is the path VS Code should open by default when
    // connected. This is typically a file mount in .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": null
    },

    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": []

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Uncomment the next line if you want start specific services in your Docker Compose config.
    // "runServices": [],

    // Uncomment the next line if you want to keep your containers running after VS Code shuts down.
    // "shutdownAction": "none",

    // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing curl.
    // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl",

    // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

and the docker-compose.yml that has been generated in .devcontainer:

**.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2090316 for license information.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

version: '3'
services:
  # Update this to the name of the service you want to work with in your docker-compose.yml file
  app_web:
    # If you want add a non-root user to your Dockerfile, you can use the "remoteUser"
    # property in devcontainer.json to cause VS Code its sub-processes (terminals, tasks, 
    # debugging) to execute as the user. Uncomment the next line if you want the entire 
    # container to run as this user instead. Note that, on Linux, you may need to 
    # ensure the UID and GID of the container user you create matches your local user. 
    # See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root for details.
    #
    # user: vscode

    # Uncomment if you want to override the service's Dockerfile to one in the .devcontainer 
    # folder. Note that the path of the Dockerfile and context is relative to the *primary* 
    # docker-compose.yml file (the first in the devcontainer.json "dockerComposeFile"
    # array). The sample below assumes your primary file is in the root of your project.
    #
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      # Update this to wherever you want VS Code to mount the folder of your project
      - .:/workspace:cached

      # Uncomment the next line to use Docker from inside the container. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/samples/docker-from-docker-compose for details.
      # - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 

    # Uncomment the next four lines if you will use a ptrace-based debugger like C++, Go, and Rust.
    # cap_add:
    #   - SYS_PTRACE
    # security_opt:
    #   - seccomp:unconfined

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

Why does this auto-generate of the remoting config in visual studio break the core VM? What have I misunderstood and got wrong here?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, so, a bit of a think later, the .devcontainer\docker-compose.yml ends with:

```
 # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

The default command should have been apache2-foreground which starts Apache2 in the php images. So removing that, and relying on the command at the end of the main dockerfile for the php image solved the problem.

**.devcontainer\docker-compose.yml**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2090316 for license information.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

version: '3'
services:
  # Update this to the name of the service you want to work with in your docker-compose.yml file
  app_web:
    # If you want add a non-root user to your Dockerfile, you can use the "remoteUser"
    # property in devcontainer.json to cause VS Code its sub-processes (terminals, tasks, 
    # debugging) to execute as the user. Uncomment the next line if you want the entire 
    # container to run as this user instead. Note that, on Linux, you may need to 
    # ensure the UID and GID of the container user you create matches your local user. 
    # See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root for details.
    #
    # user: vscode

    # Uncomment if you want to override the service's Dockerfile to one in the .devcontainer 
    # folder. Note that the path of the Dockerfile and context is relative to the *primary* 
    # docker-compose.yml file (the first in the devcontainer.json "dockerComposeFile"
    # array). The sample below assumes your primary file is in the root of your project.
    #
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      # Update this to wherever you want VS Code to mount the folder of your project
      - .:/workspace:cached

      # Uncomment the next line to use Docker from inside the container. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/samples/docker-from-docker-compose for details.
      # - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 

    # Uncomment the next four lines if you will use a ptrace-based debugger like C++, Go, and Rust.
    # cap_add:
    #   - SYS_PTRACE
    # security_opt:
    #   - seccomp:unconfined

    # LEAVE THE DEFAULT COMMAND ALONE!
```